# How to promote online linked clone vm to full clone vm in Vsphere?

Tags: clone, vmware, vsphere

We are facing an issue to promote the online linked clone vm disks on vCenter.
Linked clone vm is in power on state and it's parent vm is in power off state.
We are using vSphere PromoteDisks() api to promote the linked clone vm.

## Executing the following command using PowerCLI:

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $LinkedVM.ExtensionData.PromoteDisks($true, $null);

## Exception :

disk '[datastorename] link1/link1_1.vmdk' is only supported on native unmanaged linked clone disks."
At line:1 char:1

- $LinkedVM.ExtensionData.PromoteDisks($true, $null);
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VimException
  ```

One of the VMware KB articles mentions that “To promote the disks of a powered on VM, the VM cannot have snapshots.”,
https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/eda658cb-b729-480e-99bc-d3c961055a38/dc769ba5-3cfa-44b1-a5f9-ad807521af19/doc/vim.VirtualMachine.html#promoteDisks

In our case linked clone is in power on state and is not having any snapshot.
Goal is to promote the online linked clone vm or merge the parent vm disks to the linked clone vm disks? What are the prerequisites for it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `[datastorename] link1/link1_1.vmdk` is a NATIVE disk.
Native delta disks are not supported for promotion.
You check the deltaDiskFormat of `link1_1.vmdk` and change it to supported format (eg: seSparseFormat) either by SVMOTION to another datastore or cloning this VM

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29938715)